# Android App Compact Libary ToolBar do not show the Activity Title

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been through all the posts here and the suggested solutions but nothing worked for me.I have already spent 2 days and on the verge of giving up Android. So here I am seeking help from you guys,any help you suggest is highly appreciated. Here is my code ,please let me know if I am missing anything.

build.gradle

```
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    }
```

toolbar.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@android:color/black"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

styles.xml

```
 <resources>

        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        </style>

    </resources>
```

colors.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <color name="colorPrimary">#E64A19</color>

    </resources>
```

activity_maim.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"

            />
        <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />``

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.toolbarexample" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.toolbarexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setTitle("Groups history");
             //also tested using
            //this.setTitle("My ToolBar");
           // toolbar.setTitle("My ToolBar");


        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Why do you do this ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); You have already had toolbar. You should use toolbar

Comment: As you can the commented part I initially used setSupportActionBar(toolbar);toolbar.setTitle("My ToolBar"); but it does not work...so tried implementing other options suggested in this group but still it doesn't work.Even I added the title in the toolbar.xml to test still no result.

Comment: Are you sure your toolbar!= null? Check it out. And you better extends AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.Yes I am sure about the toolbar not being null.But now the problem is fixed and am happy.The solution was to use the **AppCompatActivity**  but  also the Android Studio IDE was problematic,it couldnot add this library-compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0" so I had to do File>Invalidate Caches/Restart and then it worked .But also I made a mistake of calling R.id.toolbar instead of R.id.tool_bar.Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. You dont need to check `if (toolbar != null)`, it always must be not null.
2. You dont need to set `id` to include layout `<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>`. And you can calling `R.id.toolbar`.
3. You better use vertical orientation `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` in your activity layout.
4. You better extends `AppCompatActivity`